# supabase.auth.session is not a function in React App

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';

const supabase = createClient('httpsfwefwfwfwf', 'wfw');

function App() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const session = supabase.auth.session();
        setUser(session ? session.user : null);

        const { data: authListener } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(
            async (event, session) => {
                setUser(session ? session.user : null);
            }
        );

        return () => {
            authListener.unsubscribe();
        };
    }, []);

    async function handleLogin() {
        const { error } = await supabase.auth.signIn({ provider: 'google' });
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error logging in:', error);
        }
    }

    async function handleLogout() {
        const { error } = await supabase.auth.signOut();
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error logging out:', error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleLogin} style={{display: user ? 'none' : 'block'}}>Login with Google</button>
            <button onClick={handleLogout} style={{display: user ? 'block' : 'none'}}>Logout</button>
            {user && <div><p>Email: {user.email}</p></div>}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

when running "npm start" I receive these logs

```
Uncaught TypeError: supabase.auth.session is not a function
    at App.js:10:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24866:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27039:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26984:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:26769:1
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:1)
```

I've upgraded to the newest version with "npm install @supabase/supabase-js@latest"

Tried running the code with "npm start" and expected to see the 2 buttons
Instead only a white page and the error logs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getSession` method to get the user's session.

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.getSession();
```

https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-getsession